# Center Imagebutton in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Imagebutton, a horizontal Line which should be under the imagebutton and below this horizontal line I have a Textview.

Somehow, I can't center the Imagebutton, despite using `android:gravity="center"`

And also I can't set the horizontal line between Imagebutton and TextView. Please help

`about.xml`

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Linearlayout ,  two attributes are for positioning of views-->

**1)** android:gravity
 **2)**  android:layout_gravity

Their name should help you :

> **android:gravity** sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.
>
> **android:layout_gravity** sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its
>   parent.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_gravity="center"`instead of `android:gravity="center"` in the `ImageButton`.

Comment: Thank you, works like charm. What is the main difference between both?

Comment: `gravity` specifies gravity of its child and `layout_gravity` specifies its gravity in the parent.

Comment: I see thank you.  I can accept answer in 7 minutes, don't worry, wont forget it.